# Django, custom fields, to_python, and displaying serialized text as-is in Django admin

Tags: django, serialization, django-admin

I have a complex object that I'm storing serialized in a text field. For most purposes, I want the object pulled from the database to be that complex object. However, when I'm editing it in a form, I just want to see that serialized text in the field.

I tried using the `value_to_string` function but it appears as if it isn't being called at all when editing the record from with admin.

What do I do so that the raw serialized text shows up in the admin text field?

Comment: are you saying that admin does not show the content of a model's text field? please clarify the question.

Comment: The field is a custom field with a `to_python` method. So when it retrieves the value from the database, it deserializes it. I want the serialized version to show up as the content of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Since the admin already uses the value of your model field, one option would be re-serializing it for editing...

See also [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides):

> This provides a quick-and-dirty way to override some of the Field
>   options for use in the admin. formfield_overrides is a dictionary
>   mapping a field class to a dict of arguments to pass to the field at
>   construction time.

Comment: So which method in the `Field` class do I add so that the value is re-serialized? I thought that would be value_to_string but it isn't. Looks like `formfield_overrides` allows you to change general, basic options for all fields of a given type. This wouldn't let me change the value of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the same problem, but I figured out a way to change the field value in the admin form before displaying it. I explained how to use a custom widget and an custom admin form in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11317656/1225621).

Note that the custom widget only helps you to display the value in a different format. It won't parse the input value back to an object, although I believe that would be possible too.